# How to disable backup when a mysql db is freshly restored from a snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

It seems like the moment a mysql db is restored form a snapshot, it instantly starts a backup.

[image]

But for my purpose, I only restore this snapshot to create a db instance for read only. I don't need to backup anything.

I checked the `restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot` API and there is no parameter that allows me to turn off backup.

So how can I turn it off? Do I instantly modify the db and set automatic-backup to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried below.

From cli

```
aws rds modify-db-instance \
--db-instance-identifier mydbinstance \
--backup-retention-period 0 \
--apply-immediately
```

By API

```
https://rds.amazonaws.com/
?Action=ModifyDBInstance
&DBInstanceIdentifier=mydbinstance
&BackupRetentionPeriod=0
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&Timestamp=2009-10-14T17%3A48%3A21.746Z
&AWSAccessKeyId=<AWS Access Key ID>
&Signature=<Signature>
```